# Structure of directory in linux

Tags: linux, filesystems, directory-listing

On a linux system, when we do the `ls` command, there's always the `.` and `..` pointers pointing respectively to the current and previous directory. I understand why `..` is useful to go back to the previous directory, but what exactly is the utility of `.`?

Comment: See this thread: [what are some uses of .(single period) & ..(double period) in the shell command line](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/118175/what-are-some-uses-of-single-period-double-period-in-the-shell-command)

Answer (score 1):

`cd` isn't the only utility that takes a directory as an operand. Any operation you want to apply to the current directory could make use of the `.` moniker.

To find a file somewhere in the current dir:

`find . -name myfile -type f`

Or to set permissions on everything in the current dir:

`chmod -R 755 .`

Those are only two examples, but `.` and `..` are both used extensively whenever you want to operate on a directory with a relative path.

One last example, using your mentioned `cd`, would be if you're drilling down a long directory structure. You can avoid a lot of typing with `.`.

```
/foo/bar/my/dir/is/so/long $ pwd
/foo/bar/my/dir/is/so/long
/foo/bar/my/dir/is/so/long $ cd ./and/then/some/more
/foo/bar/my/dir/is/so/long/and/then/some/more $ pwd
/foo/bar/my/dir/is/so/long/and/then/some/more
```

Comment: Also, `.` refers to the current directory.  So if you wanted to execute a command that wasn't in your system path but you were in its directory you could write `./<some command>` and your shell would execute it.

Comment: If I write `cd other/directory`, does bash internally add the `./` prefix?